# Map Google App to non-primary account for google for business

Tags: google-app-engine

I have made a website using Google app engine that I would like to map to my own domain.

I have added the app as a service following instructions given.

I then attempted to add a new URL for the app so that it would could be fount at www.mydomain.com.

How when I attempt to add this domain I get the error "The term mydomain.com is not allowed".

I have searched all over and can't seem to find out what the issue is. I have contacted support and they have said they can't help me with non-core services, even though this is an error given in the control panel.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a google apps account for that domain and are trying to bind the gae application to this domain.
If so, put only "www" in. It will add the application to www.mydomain.com.
Adding the application to the root( mydomain.com ) is not possible in general. (But for the primary domain its possible to set a redirection)

Comment: That's what I did though. But when I click add I get that error. "the term is not allowed"

Comment: Hm.. thats strange. Have you tried to add another name (not www, maybe xyz) and see if this works?. Maybe www is blocked by Google-Pages or something (if so, check the service "sites" (CPanel -> Settings -> Services)

Comment: I have tried others and google sites is deactivated. I think I have found the problem:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6545

turns out you can't attach Google apps to secondary independant domains.

Do you know if there is a work around?

Comment: What do you mean with "independant"? We have multiple domains in one google apps account (as alias), and we have bound them to gae applications (Some to the same, some to different apps).
This works for www and the like, not for naked domains (i dont know any way map naked secondary domains, we did dns magic to redirect abc.com to www.abc.com).
And make sure, you added a top level domain to your apps account. Its possible to verify something like test.abc.com, but in this case you wont be able to bind any gae application.